# ValueError at /profiles/followers/admin/ Cannot query "flash": Must be "User" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Here I am confuse with a queryset. I just want to grab the list of followers of my followers.
e.g: if user1 is in my followers list and i can see him inside the follower list template but I also want see how many followers and following does user1 have.
Right now i am facing an error : **ValueError at /profiles/followers/admin/  Cannot query "flash": Must be "User" instance.**

```
views.py

 user = context['user']
        # user = self.request.POST.get("close")
        # print()
        myfollowers = user.is_following.all()
        myfollowers_data = []

        for target_list in myfollowers:
               single_follower = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=target_list)
               single_follower_count = single_follower.is_following.count()
               myfollowers_data.append(single_follower_count)
```

if more information is require than tell me in comment session, i will update my question with that information.

Comment: There is nothing with the name `flash`. So, plz check your code and make an edit.

Comment: Flash is user name of a user which is passing through the query set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are only using `string` flash which is not instance. So, using [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) will do the job.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

user = get_object_or_404(User, username=context['user'])
```